# Custom Directive to sync inputs with own FormControl implementation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

In our current project we have pretty advanced requirements for our individual FormFields since this is going to be a long one I'll go through the steps one by one:

Environment:
Angular 10+, Angular Material, Reactive Forms

**What I want:**

Forms go through multiple hands (users A, B and C, A before B before C and so on). Now A enters something in a specific field and sends the form over to B, who sees whether A entered something in a field. A's input is now called the `fallbackValue`.

Every field that A touched is now to be highlighted as `new` for B. Preferably by adding a small tag as a `matSuffix` to the FormField.
Now comes the complicated part:

B saves his progress and later reopens the document. Now B should be able to remove anything he added to a control, but if he does so, the `fallBackValue` entered by A should now fill the input (not necessarily the FormControl but I could live with that). And be styled in a way, so that B sees that this is not a value they entered, but one that one of the previous users entered (I was thinking of something simple like upping the transparency of the text or something).

**Example:**

> Let's pretend A entered "Hello!"
>
> No B sees that Input displaying "Hallo!" and a tag that marks this input as "new"
>
> B wants to overwrite this with "Good day!" now the "new" tag disappears and the input just display "Good day!" like any normal input.
>
> Later B comes back and removes "Good day!", therefore the input defaults to the `fallBackValue` of "Hallo!" set beforehand by A, which is now displayed slightly different than "Good day!" to signal that it is not a value specified by B.

The information needed to determine the `fallbackValue` and whether a entry is `new` I get from the backend (which is a whole other mess I have to figure out, but out of scope for here).

**Ideas / What I tried:**

I tried to approach this problem by writing my own `CustomFormControl`, which extends the normal Angular FormControlClass:

```
export class CustomFormControl extends FormControl {
  isNew: boolean;
  fallBackValue: boolean | string | any[];

  constructor(formState?: any, validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null,
              asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null,
              isNew?: boolean, fallBackValue?: boolean | string | any[]) {
    super(formState, validatorOrOpts, asyncValidator);
    this.isNew = isNew;
    this.fallBackValue = fallBackValue;
  }
}
```

Now idealy I would like to have a functionality like the Angular ´FormControlNameDirective´ that syncs the input element with my `CustomFormControl` and allows me to access and manipulate the control.

We are currently using ´mat-form-fields´ for everything. I would really like to not reimplement `NgControl` `FormControlDirective` and `FormControlNameDirective` one by one, since that really does not sound 'future proof' to me.
And since the behaviour above is needed in roughly 300+ inputs throughout the application I need to find a generally applicable solution.

Any ideas or directions would be amazing. I have been trying to get a grip on this for a few weeks now but however I go about and try to acces the `FormControl` applied to a `FormField` I never get my `CustomFormControl`

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [`ControllValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). A few examples: https://indepth.dev/search?query=ControlValueAccessor

Comment: If I understand you correct, you recommend building my own Input components to manage all that? And register my own inputs als valid Controls by implementing `CVA`?
Since we have about 10 forms with 100-300 inputs each this sounds like a lot of manuell boilerplate to me.

Comment: You just need to handle `fallBack` value, right? So just add that logic in your `CVA` > `writeValue` method. I think you will only need to create single directive with `CVA` and use it in all of your form-controls. Of course, if you have different types of inputs (text, radio, checbox, etc), then you will have to create multiple `CVA`s.

Comment: I see where you are going, but I would also want to access styling options for the input as well as the ability to add a custom html element within the form Field for the "new" plaque. And so far this only fixes the problem with the displayed value. Although I am still struggling to see how I would go about accessing the CustomFormControl and therefore the fallbackvalue

Comment: If you are using angular material I think you should look at Custom Form Field Control https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

Comment: @JEY this may be part of my solution but I really need to pass information down to my FormFields which would idealy happen alongside the FormContol Object passed down to it.

Comment: When you say, the form goes through multiple hands, I'm assuming different users are working on the application. Is the data entered by users saved in DB ?

Comment: yes we will have about 7.000 users working with the application, not on the code base. Yes asume that every step I described above is persited in our database. 
Meaning every edit on any field by any user

Answer (score 1):

As @shhdharmen suggested, using `ControlValueAccessor` may help in this requirements.

Below is a **[sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mcqdjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** of how I would approach this problem.

1. Define my steps in an array

```typescript
  fieldStatus = {
    fieldAt0: [],
    fieldAt1: [{ user: 'A', text: 'Hello Today A' }],
    fieldAt2: [
      { user: 'A', text: 'Hello Today By A' },
      { user: 'B', text: 'Hello Today By B' },
    ],
    fieldAt3: [
      { user: 'C', text: 'Hello Today By C' },
      { user: 'B', text: 'Hello Today By B' },
      { user: 'A', text: 'Hello Today By A' },
    ],
    fieldAt4: [
      { user: 'C', text: 'Hello Today By C' },
      { user: 'B', text: 'Hello Today By B' },
      { user: 'A', text: 'Hello Today By A' },
      { user: 'D', text: 'Hello Today By D' },
    ],
  };
```

With the above we can get the last entry and set this as our fallback

We then need to pass this to our custom input say `

```html
  <app-step-input
    [currentUser]="currentUser"
    [steps]="fieldStatus.fieldAt0"
    formControlName="fieldAt0"
  >
  </app-step-input>
```

`currentUser` will hold the identity of the current user

Lets now define the control implementing `ControlValueAccessor`

```typescript
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-step-input',
  templateUrl: './step-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./step-input.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => StepInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class StepInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  isFallback = false;
  fallBack: { user: string; text: string } = { user: '', text: '' };
  @Input() set steps(steps: any[]) {
    if (steps.length > 0) {
      this.fallBack = steps[steps.length - 1];
      this.currentValue = this.fallBack.text;
      this.isFallback = true;
    }
  }
  @Input() currentUser = '';
  currentValue = '';
  disabled = false;
  onChanges: (param: any) => void;
  onTouched: () => void;
  constructor() {}
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj && obj.length > 0) {
      this.currentValue = obj;
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanges = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  handleInputChange() {
    this.isFallback = false;
    this.onChanges(this.currentValue);
    this.onTouched();
    // console.log(this.currentValue);
  }

  handleBlur() {
    if (this.currentValue === '') {
      this.currentValue = this.fallBack.text;
      this.isFallback = true;
    }
    console.log(this.fallBack.text);
  }
  handleFocus() {
    if (this.isFallback) {
      this.currentValue = '';
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I am using `isFallback` to track whether the value is a fallback value and `fallback` to hold the fallback

the html will simply contain your control, I am using a simple input for this demo

```html
<input
  [(ngModel)]="currentValue"
  (ngModelChange)="handleInputChange()"
  (blur)="handleBlur()"
  (focus)="handleFocus()"
  type="text"
/>
<br />
<small class="tag" *ngIf="fallBack.user === currentUser">SELF </small>
<small class="tag tag-new" *ngIf="isFallback">NEW </small>
```

Now you should be able to use the `control`. The control will default to the last step in the `steps` object

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still gotta try to fit this into out material design but so far this is the only workable approach I have seen. 
Propably won't need to track the user and the backend api will need some adjustment but I expected as much. :)